# The setstate() function is called during widget building, though I have passed a pointer to it but it doesn't recognizes it

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, setstate

[Here, I'm providing the image of my main.dart class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rt19.png) I'm creating a quiz app in flutter and this is my main.dart file and the "changeQuestions" function is throwing an error in the emulator.

```
var questionIndex = 0;
  void _changeQuestions() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
    });
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Center(
            child: Text(
              'Quiz App',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: questionIndex < _questions.length
            ? Quiz(
                questions: _questions,
                index: questionIndex,
                changeQue : _changeQuestions)
            : const Center(
                child: Text('You Did It.'),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Flutter recognizes the 'changeQuestions' as a function called during widget building, though it doesn't recognizes as a pointer.
This is my quiz.dart class where I've implemented to call the 'changeQuestion' function through a pointer 'changeque'.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './questions.dart';
import './answer.dart';
 
class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int index;
  final VoidCallback changeQue;
 
  const Quiz(
      {Key? key,
      required this.questions,
      required this.index,
      required this.changeQue})
      : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Questions(
            questions[index]['Text'] as String,
          ),
        ),
        ...(questions[index]['Ans'] as List<String>).map((answer) {
          return Answer(changeQue, answer);
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is my answer.dart where the setState() method is called on 'onPressed'.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback selectHandler;
  final String receiveans;

  const Answer(this.selectHandler, this.receiveans, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: selectHandler, child: Text(receiveans)),
    );
  }
}
```

How might I go about handling this? Or, is there a better way I can go about implementing so that this appears cleaner?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `changeQue` called in the build method of the `Answer` widget? Maybe add a snippet of this widget as well

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. `Answer` is missing from the question itself.

Comment: I've provided the answer.dart class, please observe if anything is wrong.

Comment: I've tested your code on my side and everything just works (Assuming `Questions` just shows the `Text`). There is something else missing.

Comment: Yes, questions is only for displaying the text.

Comment: I've also added an image at the top and you can see how it looks on my side.

Comment: [Check out this gist](https://gist.github.com/lepsch/20286eec3f3bdcd464b148e0da8c1e47) of the code I'm saying it just works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to call setState() function inside addPostFrameCallback, this function will return callback when the build process is finished.
Might be it's work's for you.

Also check doc: [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html)

```
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
      });
    });
```